# AWS CloudFormation ignoring packages in metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to make a cloud formation template that will create a LightSail instance with apache2 on it. After running the template A LightSail instance is created but the packages defined in metadata are ignored. How do I get this to work for LightSail?

Please note that for whatever reason LightSail does not want base64 or #!/bin/bash -xe

**My template**

```
Description: AWS CloudFormation Temp to create LightSail Instance with apache2

Resources:
  LightSail:
    Type: AWS::Lightsail::Instance
    Properties:
      BlueprintId: ubuntu_20_04 # Required
      BundleId: micro_2_0 # Required
      InstanceName: test # Required

    Metadata:
      AWS::Cloudformation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            apt:
              apache2: []
      Properties:
        UserData: !Sub |
          apt-get -y update 
          mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin
          wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz
          python3 -m easy_install --script-dir /opt/aws/bin aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz

          # Start cfn-init
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LightSail --region ${AWS::Region}
          # cfn-init completed so signal success or not
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LightSail --region ${AWS::Region}
```

**The error I'm getting in my cfn-init.log**

```
root@ip-172-26-15-38:~# cd /var/log
root@ip-172-26-15-38:/var/log# cat cfn-init.log 
2021-10-15 23:24:03,413 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2021-10-15 23:24:03,414 [DEBUG] Describing resource LightSail in stack testes
2021-10-15 23:24:03,790 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2021-10-15 23:24:03,791 [DEBUG] Signaling resource LightSail in stack testes with unique ID i-0bfe0de920b806746 and status FAILURE
```

Comment: `packages defined in metadata are ignored.` - what do you mean? what is the actual issue? what packages? and I can;t see any `base64` or `#!/bin/bash -xe`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I was under the impression that packages you want installed should go under the packages part of AWS::Cloudformation::Init:. I have apache2 in the packages, which should be installed when I run cfn-init. So I'm not sure why apache is not being installed

Comment: Where did you find that `AWS::Lightsail::Instance` support UserData?

Comment: I assumed it did. I haven't found anything explicitly stating it does.